# vs 2008 crystal report add image from database

Tags: vb.net

please tell me how to display image from database on crystal repoirt the tab Picture tab. Graphic Location is not display in crystal report  vs 2008 give me answer as early as posible

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! May I refer you to this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Answer (score 0):

i didn't get your question but those two function might help you as images saved in database in a byte feild

```
Public Function BytesToImage(ByVal ImageBytes() As Byte) As Image
    Dim imgNew As Image
    Dim memImage As New System.IO.MemoryStream(ImageBytes)
    imgNew = Image.FromStream(memImage)
    memImage.Dispose()
    Return imgNew
End Function

Public Function ImageToBytes(ByVal Image As Image) As Byte()
    Dim memImage As New System.IO.MemoryStream
    Dim bytImage() As Byte

    Image.Save(memImage, Image.RawFormat)
    bytImage = memImage.GetBuffer()
    memImage.Dispose()
    Return bytImage
End Function
```